# How to verify if an instance object calls its methods with a set of arguments?

Tags: python, mocking

I have a function at module level which I'm testing. It creates and initializes a file variable and I need to assert if the write operation to the file happens with the correct set of arguments. How do I test of write() was called at all on file. As in, what do I have to mock here and how?

```py
# inside myfolder/mymodule.py
def myfunction():
   file = open("path/to/file", "a+")
   file.write("sample text")

#I need to make sure that file.write() is called with the string "sample text" in my test.
#Using mock.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the write:

```
def myfunction(file):
   file.write("sample text")
```

on the mock (just as a simple example):

```
class MockedFile():
    def __init__():
        self.was_called = 0
    def write():
        self.was_called += 1
    def assert():
        assert self.was_called > 0

mocked_file = MockedFile()
myfunction(mocked_file)
mocked_file.assert()
```

Comment: I don't want to pass it as an argument. I actually want to test that .write() was called at all on file.

Comment: make a funtion to check if the file grows

Comment: Thanks. I could do that, but was wondering if there was a simpler way to use mock and assert that write is called.

Comment: Well, use a mocked write method passing it through an argument.

Comment: Do you mean to use mock.patch(mymodule.write) & passing as an argument(For example mock_write)? It did not work in this case when I assert with mock_write.

Comment: I do not know what do you have in your code, but in here is how to mock whatever, you need to substitute it. You cannot inyect it derectly unless somehow you mock the `open` function.

Comment: That doesn't work either. That's the first thing I tried actually. Should've mentioned.